# Suit + infinitive

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to say :
*that thing doesn't suit to be here*

Can **suit** be used like that? what are the rules for that verb.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The verb *suit* is typically used like this:

> This thing just doesn't **suit me**. So, I'm gonna have to go with something different.

Regarding your specific case, I'd say it like this:

> That thing just doesn't **belong** here.

or:

> That thing seems to be **out of place**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the rule of that? Why can't suit be used in the sentence that I brought above.

Comment: I don't know anything about any rules. I just go by how I've heard this verb used.

Comment: I looked it up in a dictionary. And it looks like "suit" always takes an object. So, you can't say "suit to..."

Answer (score 2):

**["Suit to"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/suit-to)** can only be used in a phrase structured as **suit something to somebody/suit something to something** which means ***to make something appropriate for something/somebody***

- ***He can suit his conversation to whoever he's with.***

In your case it doesn't work. But it could if you changed it to:

- *That thing **isn't suitable to be** here.*

The sentence **That thing doesn't suit to be here** can be rephrased to *(depending on the context)*:

1. *That thing doesn't **belong** here*
2. *That thing doesn't **need to be** here*
3. *That thing doesn't **fit (in)** here*
4. *That thing doesn't **come in handy in** here*
5. *That thing doesn't **have a (rightful) place** here*
6. *That thing doesn't **go** here*
7. *That thing doesn't **blend in** here*

Comment: Isn't *to be* the object? Like I hate to be here, the object of hate is being here/to be here, I love helping him, the object is Helping Him, not Him alone as the object, they are all transitive verbs that need a direct object. I thought suit had the same basic rule

Comment: @ChaesarIbrani No, "to be here" is not an object. "Hate" is a catenative verb and "to be here" is its catenative complement. "Love" is also a catenative verb and "helping him" is catenative complement, not object.

Comment: @BillJ Notwithstanding anything I have said in my answer, I would say, at a push,  "suit" could be regarded as catenative. *It doesn't suit to be difficult* seems idiomatic to me. Perhaps it could be argued that there is an implied and unspoken direct object in "the boss", before "to be difficult".

Answer (score 0):

The verb ***suit*** has a wide number meanings and uses. But what we are discussing here are the two OED senses 14 - transitive (***Do you think the hat suits you?***) and 16 - intransitive (***Would Beaujolais wine suit as an accompaniment to the beef bourguignon.***)

> 14. a. To be fitted or adapted to, be suitable for, answer the requirements of.
>
> e.g. 1875   B. Jowett in tr. Plato Dialogues (ed. 2) III. 591   His
>   own explanation did not suit all phenomena.
>
> 1891   Speaker 11 July 37/1   The error of supposing that what suits a
>   small country could be readily transplanted to large European States.

And the **intransitive**:

> 16. To be suitable, fitting, or convenient; to match or be in accord.
>
> 1865   J. W. Carlyle Lett. III. 269   Say Saturday; if that does not
>   suit there will be time to tell me.
>
> 1971   ‘D. Halliday’ Dolly & Doctor Bird xiii. 193   I've done an
>   Eysenck personality inventory on you both... You wouldn't suit.

In the case of the intransitive use, there is usually a hidden compliment, even if it is not stated. e.g. *Does Saturday suit?* In this case it is just that the object of the verb is not clearly stated, but it could be *him, them, you, the condition of the pitch etc.* - or a multiplicity of implied people and conditions.

**In answer to your specific question, *Does that thing suit to be here?* - whilst the question itself is not idiomatic there is nothing especially wrong with the way *suit* is used. Normally in such as case one would say *Is that thing suitable here?*. But you could say *Does it suit, right here?*.**

Comment: Isn't *to be* the object? Like I hate to be here, the object of hate is being here/to be here, I love helping him, the object is Helping Him, not Him alone as the object, they are all transitive verbs that need a direct object. I thought suit had the same basic rule